# Parse JSON data which is in string from in AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I've made an AsyncTask to retrieve data using Node.js and RESTful APIs. I'am storing the input in StringBuilder , but the problem is that I want to retrieve a key : value pair (`Error : true/false` to be specific) from the result. Since the result in not in form of JSON, I cannot use `.get("Element")` method. Here's my AsyncTask :

```
class RegisterAsync extends AsyncTask<String , Void, Integer> {

@Override     
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    String toDO = params[0];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Boolean isError = false;
    int toReturn;
    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.14:3030/api/insert");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(toDO.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(line + '\n');
        }
        reader.close();
        Log.d("RecvdToRegisterAsync: " , sb.toString());

        //got result in sb... What next???


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
```

}

Comment: add result data also

Comment: you should post your json response (if not json... post your get response) and how you try to get the info.

Comment: In which format your response is?

Comment: what your response looks like? how you want it to be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to JSONObject or JSONArray depending on the response string. Like this:

```
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
    String key=response.get("key");
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this ;)

```
   jsonResponse = new String(serverResponse, "UTF-8");
   JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
   JSONObject json= jObject.getJSONObject("data");
    //there is the data in String format
   String data= json.getString(objectToFind);
```